# How to use a variable (a URL saved as a string) from another component?

Tags: reactjs

Question: How can I use different URLs from different components in a third component as one ?

I am learning React.js and I would like to make multiple pages. This is an example project for learning purposes. There is one page where I can see the images and info of TeamA and there is another page where I can see the images and info of TeamB.

In order to avoid duplicates, I want to separate small components. I have a Card component which displays the image of team members with name and info. I want to use this one Card component for the page TeamA and also for the page TeamB.

The only difference now is the URL for the images - there is 1 URL for TeamA and one for TeamB. It should change accordingly.

I hope I could describe the problem. Please see the code examples below.
I appreciate your help. Have a nice day!

1st Component which has a unique URL for images:

```
const TeamA = ({id}) => {
    const exampleImages = `https://url`;
    return (
        <div>
            <Teams>
                <Card teamImg={exampleImages}/>
            </Teams>
        </div>
    );
}
```

2nd Component which also has a unique URL for images:

```
const TeamB = ({id}) => {
    const exampleImagesB = `https://url`;
    return (
        <div>
            <Teams>
                <Card teamImg={exampleImagesB}/>
            </Teams>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The Component that displays the information of the Team component (above). In this component, I want to use the URLs from the other components and add it to the img tag.

```
const Card = ({ name, email, id, teamImg }) => {
    return (
      <div className='tc'>
          <img alt='image' src={`${teamImg}`}/>
          <div>
              <h2>{name}</h2>
              <p>{info}</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I think what you want is to use states, which is the one thing react is used for.  Instead of using fp, you need to have your components as a class.

Comment: @Wolfeius That's not correct... React is used for much more than just states. And there's no reason to change them from functional to class components. Just use hooks (`useState`) instead. Though I don't think that will solve his problem.

Comment: @DaxialArray You're passing the URL down to the `Card` as a prop, which is the correct way to go about it if you want the component to be reusable as you mentioned. So I'm not sure what the actual problem is. Could you maybe elaborate a bit more on what the issue is and what you're experiencing with your current solution?

Comment: Thank you for the answers!
@Phoenix1355 The problem is that no image gets displayed this way. It just shows "image" from the img alt attribute. There is no error message in the console. If I write a valid URL into the img tag, it works. But I need to use different URLs and as you mentioned, I want to reuse the component. So I assume that src={`${teamImg}`} does not receive the URL from the other component.

Answer (score 0):

You can make team a functional component of it's own:

```
const Team = ({id, imageUrl}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Teams>
                <Card teamImg={imageUrl}/>
            </Teams>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Then you can pass imageUrl into your teams at a higher level without writing them out as separate components each time.

For example if you have your different urls as an array, this could be the component above team:

```
const AllTeams = () => {
    const images = [{ id: 1, url: 'url1' }, { id: 2, url: 'url2' }];
    return (
        <>
            { images.map(image => <Team key={image.id} imageUrl={image.url} />) }
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Danke schön @Ramorie!
Daran habe ich nicht gedacht. Ich versuche es. Danke für die Beschreibungen!

Comment: No problem let me know if you need more help